# HttpResponseRedirect appends passed url to current url

Tags: django, httpresponse

I'm using djnago `HttpResponseRedirect` to return previous page after login. The problem is, I give a wrong redirect url (combination of `next` url and current url)

Assuming I've loged in from "mysite.com/home" and the login page url is "mysite.com/login" I want to return to "mysite.com/home" **but the redirect url is mysite.com/login/?next=/home/** .

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my `view`, responsible for login:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)

            # next is "/home/" and that is exactly what I expect
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next', reverse('products.views.show_homePage')))
```

Comment: Show us the exact value of `request.POST.get('next')` before calling redirect.

Comment: I had made a mistake getting `next` value by `request.POST` cause "next=a url" is in query string, but the value still is the same as I mentioned in the code (comment part).

Comment: Also I changed the form action url to absolute path in client side (javascript) and that solved the problem, But I have no idea what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem!

Try this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('products.views.show_homePage'))
```

make sure to include obviously: `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`

This will make the page send a redirection to your homepage.. Hopefully..

Here is what I did:

Login:

```
# Login
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/test/")  # Redirect to a tool directory page.
    form = loginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/test/")  # Redirect to a success page.
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Logout:

```
# Logout user method 
def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginregistration.views.login'))  # Redirect to a success page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me:
***Class HttpResponseRedirect*** works with three kind of urls:

(1) Fully qualified URL e.g, 'https://www.yahoo.com/search/'

(2) An absolute path with no domain e.g, '/search/'

(3) A relative path e.g, 'search/'

If your functions not returns ***Fully qualified URL*** then it might be possible reason for appending url to existing url.

Please refer the Django official documentation for more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/